# how to create hexogonal shape with css

Tags: html, css, sass

how to create hexagonal shape using HTML and css in this image the green color section with search icon

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: use `clip-path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you made a triangle instead?

```
#triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid green;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

this site may be helpful:
https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

## Here I played a bit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
 }   
.search{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10em;
    border-end-end-radius: 51px;
    border-start-end-radius: 51px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Triangle Right CSS</h2>
<div class="search">
    <div class="triangle-right"><span>search</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZlPB.png)

Change the colors, put some icons in there using googles free icons https://fonts.google.com/icons

and it'll look great!
let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following snippet. I used Font Awesome for the search icon.

```css
html{background-color:grey}
.wrapper{
  margin:40px 0 0 40px;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:20px;
  background-color:white;
}
.sub-wrapper{
  background-color:#3dce93;
  width:50px;
  border-radius:0 20px 20px 0;
  float:right;
}
.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid white;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-right i{
  position:relative; 
  top:-8px; 
  left:11px;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub-wrapper" style="cursor:pointer">
    <div class="triangle-right"> 
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a hexagon (or part of one as shown in the question) we need to make sure the slopes are at 60deg - the inner angle of a hexagon being 120deg.

One way of doing this would be to use linear-gradient background images at 60deg and -60deg as in this snippet. If you add these plus the search icon using pseudo elements you can have just one element in the HTML with one class that provides everything required:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    .searchdiv {
      --w: 20vmin;
      /* set this to what you want the width to be */
      --h: 20vmin;
      /* and the height */
      --p: 5vmin;
      /* the 'padding' (the amount of gray background)*/
      width: var(--w);
      height: var(--h);
      background-color: gray;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .searchdiv::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: var(--p);
      left: 0;
      width: calc(100% - var(--p));
      height: calc(100% - (2 * var(--p)));
      border-radius: 0 5vmin 5vmin 0;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, palegreen 0 65%, transparent 65% 100%), linear-gradient(60deg, white 0 35%, palegreen 35% 100%);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .searchdiv::after {
      content: 's';
      /*replace with whatever is the code for the search icon in whatever icon font you are using */
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="searchdiv"></div>
</body>
```